# ObjectListView Set first displayed item

Tags: c#, objectlistview

Is it possible to programmatically set the first displayed item in a BrightIdeasSoftware `ObjectListView`?
In other words I want to scroll down the list to make another item than the first in the list displayed at the top.
I cant't find any member that does so.

Comment: Since its based off of a `ListView`, maybe the closest you can get is `EnsureVisible`, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ensurevisible(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, this works. But it doesn't scroll the list if the item is visible. I need to force the list to scroll such that a specific item is at the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
objectListView1.TopItemIndex = n;
```

Comment: Actually `objectListView1.EnsureModelVisible(modelObject);` is intended to make a specific model object visible (scrolling it into view).